# How to download a collection in NCBI in python

Tags: python, database, list, dataframe, ncbi

I have a collection in ncbi with 100 sequences
I want to download all the sequences and make a list of features

An example

```
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..866
                     /organism="Boletus roseogriseus"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /country="Czech Republic"
                     /collection_date="23-Aug-2007"
```

Now I would like to make a list of the source features for all the sequences 
for example

```
ID /country       /collection_date 
1  Czech Republic 23-Aug-2007
2  Italy          ....
```

Any ideas what kind of tools I can use or if it is possible to use python for that?

Comment: What's an "NCBI"?

Comment: is a database for genome sequences